# is there a way to call a function just once when window is less than 900px

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having trouble with a marquee plug in, I want the marquee to began when the window with is less than 900 px, otherwise the marque would not run, but when i run a window resize event, the marquee is being created thousends of times, one in top of the other, 
Here is the code:

```
var resizeTimer;

$(window).on('resize', function(e) {

clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
if ($(window).width() < 900) {
        $('.footer').marquee({
            //speed in milliseconds of the marquee
            duration: 10000,
            //gap in pixels between the tickers
            gap: 100,
            //time in milliseconds before the marquee will start animating
            delayBeforeStart: 1000,
            //'left' or 'right'
            direction: 'left',
            //true or false - should the marquee be duplicated to show an effect of continues flow
            duplicated: true
        });

    }
    else {

    }


 }, 500);

});

<div class="footer">
    <div class="pueblatemp">Puebla</div>
    <div class="warlotemp">Warlo</div>
    <div class="difference">Difference</div>
    <div class="time">Time</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Set a variable when you create the marquee. Then check if the variable is set before creating it again.

Answer (score 0):

I would go ahead and call

```
$(window).off('resize');
```

when your condition is met so the event is no longer bound.